# refrigerator not cooling

Tags: repair, switch, refrigerator, relay

I have a GE side by side and the freezer is working fine, but the refrigerator is not cooling (not hot kind og like room temperature). I replaced the relay switch how long before I know if that was the issue.

Comment: What model refrigerator is this?

Answer (score 3):

First off, understand how a refrigerator moves cold air around between the freezer compartment and the cold food compartments. Here is a generic diagram. 
[image]

So make sure you have not stored something in a way that is blocking the airflow. If not, then find and inspect those air pathways to see if there is ice, mold or some other material built up and blocking it. I have had a small piece of cellophane from something get caught in the vent and cause this.

If that's not it, roll the fridge out and vacuum the dust off of the evaporator coils. Diminished capacity will allow the cooling to handle the freezer, but not much else, so the temperature controls will often prioritize the freezer.